# using array_merge_recursive to merge arrays together but then only doing stuff with the new contents added to the array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

If you found the title misleading, sorry. I couldn't really come up with a good title for this question.

I have two arrays, that I'm merging together in a function:

```
$arr1['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo1";
$arr1['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo2";
$arr1['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo3";

$arr2['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo4";
$arr2['something']['secondary_something'][]="foo5";

function something($array_, $array_new) {

$array=array_merge_recursive($array_,$array_new); // to combine/merge both arrays

print_r($array);//debugg

}
```

Now that function simply prints this (which is all good):

```
Array ( [something] => Array ( [secondary_something] => Array ( [0] => foo1 [1] => foo2 [2] => foo3 [3] => foo4 [4] => foo5 ) ) )
```

But I need to work with the new data, that has been merged to the primary array. So I need to work `$arr2`, but only once it has been merged with `$arr1`.

When I say I need to "work with the new data", `var_export()` is one of the things I need to do with the array.

If I simply do a `echo var_export($array_new,true);`, I get this:

```
array ( 'something' => array ( 'secondary_something' => array ( 0 => 'foo4', 1 => 'foo5', ), ), )
```

When I need this:

```
array ( 'something' => array ( 'secondary_something' => array ( 3 => 'foo4', 4 => 'foo5', ), ), )
```

^^ Notice how the array keys are 3 and 4, not 1 and 2. Because it has been merged with the primary array (`$arr1`).

Hope you guys understand what I'm trying to do.

Any ideas?

Thanks xD

Comment: Is array_merge really necessary? If you are always adding new elements and don't need it to skip those elements that are the same in both arrays, you can just manually add them on to the array. When manually added on you can use array_pop and count to get the information you need to add the new items to a new array. Maybe not array_pop as that will remove it from the old array, but you get what I'm saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo var_export(array_intersect($array['something']['secondary_something'], $arr2['something']['secondary_something']), true);
```

**EDIT** This works, but you lose the multidimensional aspect of the array. You'll need to write a recursive function to step through the entire array if you want to preserve the `something` and `secondary_something` aspect in your var_export

Comment: thats just returning all of the array, as `var_export($array,true)` would.

Comment: Yeah it has to do with the fact that it's a multidimensional array, I'm working on it